# How to remove (disassociate) relationship without delete in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assuming the following models:

```
class Thing
  has_many :whats
end

class What
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

Having a particuler `Thing`, I want to disassociate all `whats` from it but I don't want to delete/destroy the `whats`. I just need `What.thing = null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution in the terminal would be to run the console, go through all the `Whats` and update the `thing_id` to `nil`

```
rails c
What.all.each do |what| what.update(thing_id: nil) end
```

Comment: I need to do it as part of a process, but this got me what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More efficient would be to do:

```rb
What.joins(:thing).where(things: @thing).destroy_all
```

or

```rb
What.where(thing_id: @thing.id).destroy_all
```

Comment: This will destroy the Whats. Definitely not what you want to use and won't achieve what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

A really efficient option is update_all. This would run 1 query to update the records and won't instantiate all the records in your db in memory. However, note that update_all will not execute any callbacks on the model and it won't update the timestamp fields. But it doesn't appear that's a requirement.

```
What.where(thing_id: @thing.id).update_all(thing_id: nil)
```